# No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "focusin", listener: (this: Document, ev: FocusEvent)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am having some issues trying to overload the addEventListener here, when trying to add/remove eventListener in this useEffect, the following error is encountered:

`No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(type: 1"focusin\", listener: (this: Document, ev: FocusEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.   Argument of type '(e: FocusEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: FocusEvent) => any'.      Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.        Type 'FocusEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'FocusEvent<Element, Element>': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.     Argument of type '(e: FocusEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.`

```
import { useState, FocusEvent, useEffect } from 'react';

interface Element {
    removeEventListener(type: 'focus' | 'focusin' | 'focusout', listener: (event: FocusEvent) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
    addEventListener(type: 'focus' | 'focusin' | 'focusout', listener: (event: FocusEvent) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}

const useActiveElement = () => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState<EventTarget>();

    const handleFocusIn = (e: FocusEvent) => {
        if (!e.target) return;
        if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') return;
        setActive(e.target);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('focusin', handleFocusIn); //This line
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('focusin', handleFocusIn); //This line
        };
    }, []);

    return active;
};
```

We are running typescript on nextjs 13's intial settings, which is strict

We tried to overload with the interface above, but it did not help. We've tried looking at docs but can't find anything, and searching the error gives a few results, none of which has helped. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why are you trying to change the type of the `addEventListener` function? Have you verified that this actually works at runtime?

Comment: I think the correct approach would be to infer the type of `document.addEventListener` second argument, which is probably `Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>[1]`, although you probably would need to do further work on `.tagName` due to the fact that it's not a standard prop of `EventType` (on `e.target`). Summarizing, `const handleFocusIn: Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>[1]` should do the job, although you should infer the type elsewhere for readability

Comment: @TobiasS. It indeed work at runtime, the reason I'm trying to change the TypeScript is throwing errors, hence it prevents me from building the app.

Comment: @briosheje That worked wonders, thank you!

Here's what I ended up doing: 

`const handleFocusIn: Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>[1] = (e: Event) => {
  if (!e.target) return;
  if ((e.target as HTMLElement).tagName === 'BUTTON') return;
  setActive(e.target);
 };
`
Would you mind explaining why adding 

`Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>[1] ` works? I am not using handleFocusIn anywhere else, so why is TypeScript not able to infer correctly here?

Comment: I will add an answer below, although my answer technically deviates from the question because rather than overloading the type, we are just using the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overloading, you probably would rather want to infer the property from the  document type.

The problem with your code is that you are trying to assume the signature of the addEventListener callback, although you didn't manage to, yet trying to override it would require to override the Document api, which is something that should be avoided here; you usually override the Document api if you need to **add** something that comes from external libraries of it, like libraries adding something to the `window` or `document` object.

The correct way to procede in these scenarios, in my opinion, is the following:

1. Inspect the signature and try to guess where it is coming from: in this case, you can see that the type of `document.addEventListener` is `Document.addEventListener<T>`, where the generic `T` is a string that represents all the possible events of `addEventListener`. Because of that, the type of our event listener is going to be `Document.addEventListener<'focusin'>`.
2. From the above function, we want to get the type of the second argument of it. For that we could use `infer`, but luckily out of box typescript actually has an utility type named `Parameters`, which conveniently returns the type of the arguments of a generic type. So, to get the parameters, we do `Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>`.
3. From the parameters, we want to get the type of the second argument, hence, since the arguments are Iterable, you can just get the index 1 of it (second element), hence our expression becomes: `Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>[1]`, which literally means "Take the type of the second argument of the function Document.addEventListener and return it". This will end up with a signature which is compatible with the second argument of `document.addEventListener`.

As a side note, the only problem we still will have is that `e.target` is going to be an `EventTarget`, while you want to act on it in specific cases, like if it actually is an HTMLButtonElement.

For that kind of situations, I personally recommend using **type guards**, which lets you have further control on it. For your case specifically, you can do this:

```
function isEventTargetButton(target: EventTarget): target is HTMLButtonElement {
  return (target as HTMLButtonElement).tagName === 'BUTTON';
}
```

So that when you use it in your code, e.target will be inferred properly:

```
if (e.target && isEventTargetButton(e.target) {
   // e.target is `HTMLButtonElement`, type completion will work as intended.
}
// Here, e.target will be `EventTarget`.
```

So, to summarize, your code will look like something like this:

```
function isEventTargetButton(target: EventTarget): target is HTMLButtonElement {
  return (target as HTMLButtonElement).tagName === 'BUTTON';
}

const useActiveElement = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState<EventTarget>();

  const handleFocusIn: Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>[1] = (e) => {
    if (!e.target) return;
    if (isEventTargetButton(e.target)) return;
    setActive(e.target);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('focusin', handleFocusIn); //This line
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('focusin', handleFocusIn); //This line
    };
  }, []);

  return active;
};
```

A final side note is that you should make a specific type for `Parameters<Document['addEventListener']>[1]` for readability purposes. I'm letting the above example as-is, although making it more readable is definitely something you want to do.

A stackblitz to play around with it is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/next-typescript-pv65sz?file=hooks%2FuseActiveElement.ts